# How to reference an object (gridview) globally in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

Is there any way I can reference a GridView object as a variable within my code behind page so I can refer to it once rather than multiple times?

I'm trying to make my code easier for me to update, and easier to transport. The less references I have to use the better!

This is an example of how my code sort of looks at the moment, there must be a better way of declaring the var GridView_ variable outside of the scope of each void?

```
public class GlobalVars
{
    // Button Toggle
    public static bool boolToggleView = false;

    // Column Indexes
    public static int Column1Index = new int();     
}

protected void GetColumnIndexes()
{
    // GridView Variable
    var GridView_ = GridViewName;

    // Column Indexes
    GlobalVars.Column1Index = Utility.GetColumnIndexByName(GridView_, "Column1");
}   

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // GridView Variable
    var GridView_ = GridViewName;

    if (GlobalVars.boolToggleView)
    {
        GlobalVars.boolToggleView = false;
    }
    else
    {
        GlobalVars.boolToggleView = true;
    }

    // Bind GridView
    GridView_.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I believe that one user control can make the work for you. Rather than that the static variables you use are the same for all users per pool, and you also not lock them for multi thread access - they are not work as you think they are.

Comment: Sorry Aristos, I am not entirely following what you mean?

Comment: I mean that the static variables are the same for all of your users.

Comment: Ah right,.well it's just an internal site I am running, nothing major as I'm not really a developer! I set the values each time the page is posted, it was just a better way than I was doing previously of declaring variables within each scope individually. Is there a better way of declaring a variable which can be referenced throughout the page code behind and isn't shared?

Comment: The session. How ever I am not actually understand what you try to archive here.

Comment: The main reason is to have variables I can update/use from anywhere on the page. This is also true for what my original question was about here, I would also like to do this for a specific grid view if I can without re-declaring it.

Comment: The GridView only exists on the page you are viewing it so you can only change it by accessing the variable in the corresponding code behind page. I think the way to go here was to maintain the status of the GridView in the database or the session and modify the GridView accoringly as you display it

Comment: I don't need to declare the gridview for access in another page, I want to refer to it via a variable in the same page so that I am not declaring the gridview multiple times in the codebehind.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you correctly.. but in the aspx-page you assign a ID to the GridView and you can access the GridView by using the assigned ID like a variable throughout the whole code behind file.

Comment: Ultimately I think you're right. If you can put that an an answer I will mark it as such for you!